# WPF Trouble Updating a Textbox from a variable

Tags: wpf, vb.net, binding, inotifypropertychanged

Using WPF, and VB.net, I want to update a textbox in a textblock with the current date and time. I use a timer, and it seems to be firing, and setting an object property to "Now".
And I am using iNotifyPropertyChanged.

All I get is an empty textbox with no data in it. Can you help?  Maybe my context is off?

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBlock DataContext="oTime"> 
        <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" 
                 Width="200" Height="50" Foreground="Black" 
                 Text="{Binding Path=oTime.TimeUpdate}"></TextBox>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**VB Code**

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Threading

Class MainWindow
  Public oTime As TimeUpdate = New TimeUpdate
  Private dpTimer As DispatcherTimer

  Private Sub TextBlock_SourceUpdated(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Data.DataTransferEventArgs)

  End Sub

  Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
      dpTimer = New DispatcherTimer
      dpTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)
      AddHandler dpTimer.Tick, AddressOf TickMe
      dpTimer.Start()
  End Sub

  Private Sub TickMe()
      oTime.TimeUpdate = Now.ToString
      Debug.Print(oTime.TimeUpdate)
  End Sub

End Class

Public Class TimeUpdate
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

  Private sTime As String

  'Declare the Event
  Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

  Public Property TimeUpdate() As String
      Get
          Return sTime

      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As String)
          sTime = value
          'Call onPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
          OnPropertyChanged("TimeUpdate")
      End Set

  End Property

  Protected Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal name As String)
      RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(name))
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: While its perfectly valid, why do you put a TextBox inside a TextBlock? A Textblock is a lightweight label to display just a simple text. Just remove the textblock, its not necessary.

Comment: I dont know why.  I was just trying different things to make it work.  I tried to change something in the textblock and it wouldnt let me. Dont remember now.  Like I said, I have only been coding WPF for a few days now, so I am getting OJT.  Several guys here told me that I should just concentrate on winforms, but I like what WPF can do. None of them work in WPF.

Comment: WPF makes alot different than windows forms. It might be difficult to switch, but it is worth it. I used winforms alot but now, i can't remember anymore how to do winforms :) i love wpf. One very crucial part of WPF is [Databinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) i suggest you read it.

Comment: Ok I will try to read up on it.  There seems to be alot on binding to database connections and stuff like that.  But I was just wanting to set the data in a textblock or textbox to a value in code.  It is alot to jump though to get a variable value in a WPF textbox.

Comment: Databinding has nothing directly to do with databases. Like you wanted to bind your TextBox.Text property to your TimeUpdate. But it seemed, you need to understand better how this binding works and what a DataContext is.

Comment: You are correct.  I saw many examples of binding to things like checkboxes and listboxes, but nothing about binding to variables.  So the context was mostly what made it work that I was missing.  I did not know how to bind to an instance of an object in code vs. a component.  I appreciate all the responses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few things seem to be missing. First the DataContext of the window is not set. You can do it the constructor:

```
Public Sub New()
    DataContext = oTime
End Sub
```

This allows your view to see the contents of the TimeUpdate class.

And then change you XAML (bind directly to the TimeUpdate property):

```
<Grid> 
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" 
             Width="200" Height="50" Foreground="Black" 
             Text="{Binding Path=TimeUpdate}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

**Update:**
Alternative way will be to add the DataContext line in the Window tag. This way your MainWindow class becomes visible to the view and you can bind to the public properties.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
```

Now create a public property to access the object:

```
Public Property OTime() As TimeUpdate
    Get
        Return oTime
    End Get
    Set
        oTime = value
    End Set
End Property
```

And bind the textbox to it:

```
<Grid> 
    <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" 
             Width="200" Height="50" Foreground="Black" 
             Text="{Binding Path=OTime.TimeUpdate}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok this made it work.  Is this the best way to do this? I appreciate all your comments so quickly.  I guess I will have to walk through this code and see if I can understand the datacontext thing better. So is this what you have to do in WPF to make a variable value display on a WPF form?  Or is there a much simpler way?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the best way. It fits your example. Another way will be to set the DataContext in your view and expose different objects thru properties (from the MainWindow class) to which you can bind. I'll extend the answer with example.

Comment: Thank you.   I will sit down tonight and see if I can step through that method of binding and see if I can follow it. That might be a better way so it will allow me to access several other objects rather than have to specify a binding each time I use a different variable.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I think your data context is off. Correctly me if I am wrong but it looks like you're setting it to a string value rather than an object. Is oTime an object you have created in the XAML as a resource? If so you will need to get it with the StaticResource. Otherwise you will need to instantiate.

Eg.

```
<TextBlock >
    <TextBlock.DataContext>
        <!-- This will instantiate the object-->
        <local:TimeUpdate/> 
    </TextBlock.DataContext>
     <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Width="200" Height="50" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=TimeUpdate}"></TextBox>
</TextBlock>
```

Edit: I just noticed that you have a TimeUpdate object instantiated in the MainWindow class. In that case I would set the DataContext of the Window to itself in the code behind and make oTime a property. That way you don't have to set the DataContext for the `TextBlock`. It would use the parent's DataContext, in this case the `Window`. You XAML would now look like below:

```
<TextBlock>
     <TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Width="200" Height="50" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=oTime.TimeUpdate}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Who downvoted that? The first part is exactly on. DataContext="oTime" sets the Datacontext to a string called oTime, and does not point to the object. Best answer

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing this:

```
 Text="{Binding Path=oTime.TimeUpdate}"
```

to:

```
 Text="{Binding Path=oTime.TimeUpdate, UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"}"
```

Answer (score -1):

try changing this

```
OnPropertyChanged("TimeUpdate")
```

to this

```
OnPropertyChanged("oTime")
```

Also, make sure you have set your DataContext on your root grid

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=.}">
```

Comment: How could altering the `OnPropertyChanged` call inside the `TimeUpdate.TimeUpdate` definition to reference the name of the `TimeUpdate` instance inside `MainWindow` possibly fix the problem?

Comment: oTime is the root of your path. As TimeUpdate is a property on oTime (which itself doesnt support INotifyPropertychanfged) you have to notify on the property path. It works, trust me :)

Comment: What I don't understand is why you're recommending referencing the name of a particular instance from within the class definition. Seems like poor design. What happens if the class is used elsewhere with a different instance name? The call will fail, yes? And that's the root of the problem - the notification isn't happening correctly.

Comment: My answer is in the context of the OP's question, design is not being debated. The solution works for the OP's problem.

Comment: And it will cause additional problems if the class is used with a different instance name. That makes it a poor answer. It doesn't actually fix the problem, it just masks it.

Comment: -1 Raising "oTime" is a bad idea, you are changing TimeUpdate, not oTime, in fact like EsotericScreenName said the name "oTime" isn't even known in this context. And while it is true that we are not talking about design, its also not helpful to give a solution that is so off, that it puts the OT on the wrong track. Sometimes hacks are fine and necessary, but it should be clearly mentioned.

Comment: I just started learning WPF a few days ago.  So if there is a better way I would love to know it.  On the other hand, this did not fix it.  Do I need to change something in the XAML code? I just cant believe it is this hard to display a variable value on a WPF textbox.

Comment: @Danks Don't worry, its not hard. ShadeofGrey gave the correct answer, read it. And maybe follow my comment underneath your inital question.

Comment: I have spent many hours trying to find an example of how to just use a timer to update a variable and get it to display on any kind of a WPF component like textbock or textbox.  There are lots of binding examples for dropdown or check boxes but not one that shows how to display a variable value from the vb code.

Comment: I assumed you had set yor datacontext - see my edit if you havent